# how to upload file using http put in android?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, httprequest, http-put

I have a REST web service and android. Now I want to request Http Put using android to call web service. In my REST web service  if user want to do Http Put he can request in terminal like this :

curl -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.org.snia.cdmi.dataobject" -v -T /home/student1/a.jpg http://localhost:8080/user1/folder/a.jpg

My question is how to set -T /home/student1/a.jpg in android using HttpPut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some snippet you can use:

```
File f = new File(...);
...
...
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://mydomain.com/some/action");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("myFile", new FileBody(f));

httpPut.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response  = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

Comment: btw, how to get the file path in File f=new file( file...) from andriod UI?

Comment: What do you mean by Android UI? Where is your file?

Comment: file is attached from local drive then upload using web service into server system

Comment: If anybody can help, I am working around the same problem and have done everything well, but when request is made, it throws exception saying "sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)", please help!!

Comment: needs external apache jar files.

solution without would be nice.

Comment: HttpPut is deprecated. any ideas?